# Compile a shell script to an executable binary with make

Tags: linux, shell, executable

I know `shc` can convert the shell script to binary, but there is obvious and famous tool to decrypt it.
So, I want to find another way to do this.

I've heard that `make` can also convert a shell script to an executable binary, but all the websites I found are about `shc`.
Does anyone know how to convert shell script to executable binary by using `make` on Linux?

Comment: `make` itself has nothing whatsoever to do with the conversion of files between different formats. Please provide a reference to where you have seen this. It is used to execute other commands based on dependency rules and file system time stamps.

Answer (score 2):

Shell scripts cannot logically be compiled into binary, because they allow the injection of new shell syntax at runtime in several ways -- for example, by constructing a new command (from variable text) which it then `exec`s, or by `source`ing a file which did not exist (or has since been modified) when the compilation took place.

shc produces a binary file, but it does not compile anything. It merely encodes the shell text file with a random key, which it embeds in the file. When the executable is run, it decodes the text and pipes it to the required shell.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. This give me some ideas.

Comment: "it decodes the text and pipes it to the required shell" No, it does not pipes it -- it simply passes the script via the `-c` argument to bash, so it could be easily seen by any user via `ps -ww` or `/proc/PID/cmdline`.

Comment: @UncleBilly  That's even more idiotic than I remembered. It also hacks off SysAdmins on systems (like Solaris) which put all the args in the `ps -ef` listing to make it flash past. And why my embedded awk scripts get executed from a temporary file like `awk -v Db=1 -f <( printf '%s' "${Awk}" )`.

Answer (score 1):

No one knows this. It's impossible.

`make` is a build automation tool. It automates software building processes, but the building of the actual software is still done by compilers and other build tools. So if you find a tool that can do what you want (for example `shc`) *then* you can *automate* it with `make`. `make` by itself doesn't compile software, code or shell scripts. It just invokes other commands, like a shell script.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation.